# If result is zero use previous. What did i do wrong?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am trying to write a function that returns a mutlidimensional array where the key is the date, and the date has two more items cost and value. with the query i am using the result will be zero rows if the stock market was closed that day (IE weekend or holiday). i want to set that days cost and value equal to the previous. Obviously i am missing something here but i dont understand.

```
function getNetWorth()
{
    // Query for First and Last date
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT min(date) as start from Transactions ORDER BY date ASC;");
    $date = $query->row_array();
    $current = $date['start'];
    $networth = array();
    while(strtotime($current)<= strtotime(date('Y-m-d')))
    {
        $cost = 0;
        $value = 0;
        $run = date('Y-m-d', $current);
        // Query for net worth for given day
        echo $current;
        $sql = "SELECT Transactions.symbol, sum(shares) AS shares, sum(shares * price) AS cost, History.close as `close`, (sum(shares) * History.close) as value ".
                "FROM Transactions INNER JOIN History ON (History.symbol = Transactions.symbol AND History.date ='".$run."') ".
                "WHERE (action <>5) AND Transactions.date <= '".$run."' GROUP BY Transactions.symbol HAVING sum(shares) > 0";
        $query = $this->db->query($sql);
        if($query->num_rows() < 1)
        {

            $date = strtotime("-1 day", $current);
            $last = date('Y-m-d', $date);
        //  $networth[$current][] = $networth[$last];
        }
        else
        {
            $result = $query->result_array();
            $cost += $result['cost'];
            $value += $result['value'];
            $networth[$current]= array("cost" => $cost, "value" => $value);

        }


        $current = strtotime("+1 day", strtotime($current));    
    }
    return $networth;
}
```

Comment: if you double quote a string, there is no need to concatenate. for arrays, delimit them with braces: `"This is a $var inside a {$arr['script']}"`

Comment: I'm not sure what the actual problem is that you're encountering, so it's hard to guess where to look. Is the commented-out line the one giving you trouble? Do you get an error message or is the result just incorrect? If so, in what way?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you format `$last` differently than `$current`, so `$networth[$last]` is not going to match anything. `$last` and `$run` are formatted the same, so you might want to change the line:

```
$networth[$run]= array("cost" => $cost, "value" => $value);
```

Comment: Well i tried that no luck. but here is what i am getting. The first one works just fine, however when it gets to the second time in the loop the output i get is `1969-12-31` but it should be `2010-06-02` can i use use my strtotime function to loop through each day like i am right now?

Comment: 1969-12-31 is a string representation of 0 Unix time, which indicates that `strtotime` failed somewhere. You have a lot of variables representing dates, and I'm not sure which you are referring to as 'the first one' and 'the second time through the loop' (there's only one loop). If it were me, I'd use the timestamp for the array index, however. Also, with the comment in the code above, the value is never set in the networth array.